# PHP array_merge return null in class

Tags: php, json, class

Why this code return null?
I check it but there is no error, And when i am call array merge with 2 default array Like *["x"=>"y","foo"=>"bar"]* it work well!
See:

```
<?php
class ClassName
{
    private $dataArray = array();
    public function put($arr){
        $this->dataArray = array_merge($arr,$this->dataArray);
        return $this;
    }    
    public function run(){
        echo json_encode($this->dataArray);
    }
}

$json = new ClassName();

$json->Test->LastLog = '123456789123456';
$json->Password      = 'Mypassword';
$json->Dramatic      = 'Cat';
$json->Things        = array("HI" => 1, 2, 3);

$json->put($json)->run();
```

Comment: You pass an object to `put` function, __why__?

Comment: $json is an array, you can print_r($json) to see @u_mulder

Comment: `$json` is an __object__ of class `Classname`.

Comment: So how can i do it? I think you've figured out what I want to do, I need too make an array like this `($json->foo->bar = "test")` and pass it to `run()` @u_mulder

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. I don't understand why you create object isntance and then pass this instance to method of the same instance.

Comment: I need too make an array like this ($json->foo->bar = "test") and pass it to run() @u_mulder

Comment: `$json->foo->bar` is an object notation. Please, make sure you understand difference between object/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Passed an object not array try like this code you got result:

```
$json->put((array)$json)->run();
```

Output is:

```
> {"\u0000ClassName\u0000dataArray":["Volvo XC90","BMW
> M4","MaclarenP1"],"Test":"123456789123456","Password":"Mypassword","Dramatic":"Cat","Things":{"HI":1,"0":2,"1":3},"0":"Volvo
> XC90","1":"BMW M4","2":"MaclarenP1"}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to pass the `$json->Test->LastLog` like this means you need to alternate you object declaration like:

```
$json = new ClassName();

$json->Test = array('LastLog'=>'123456789123456');
$json->Password      = 'Mypassword';
$json->Dramatic      = 'Cat';
$json->Things        = array("HI" => 1, 2, 3);
```

Because in your put function is array_merge expecting array but you sent a json_object instead of array. (array) is act like json_decode...
Example: Simple Object

```
$object = new StdClass;
$object->foo = 1;
$object->bar = 2;

var_dump( (array) $object );
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  'foo' => int(1)
  'bar' => int(2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked well